# Get input from CLI and create Array in PHP. Is this correct?

Tags: php, arrays, input, command-line-interface

My objective is to make a simple app that will allow me to quickly input data from the CLI and create an array, to then pass that as an entry on MariaDB on my localhost (right now I'm just dumping to check it's actually working). This was my solution for today, although it works, I feel it's a bit patchy.

Can I have your experienced take on this? I'm planning to add a check at the end to review the entries before committing the array to the database.

```
function createNewEntry()
{
    echo "Enter Practitioner Name: ";

    $getname = fgets(STDIN, 128);

    echo "Enter Practitioner email: ";

    $getemail = fgets(STDIN, 128);

    echo "Enter Practitioner Country: ";

    $getcountry = fgets(STDIN, 128);

    $thearray = array('Name' => $getname, 'email' => $getemail, 'Country' => $getcountry);

    return ($thearray);
}

$newprac = createNewEntry();

var_dump($newprac);
```

Comment: This question is too broad resulting in opinion-based answers. It would be good to focus on one specific question instead.

Comment: Well then, my question would be, Is the fgets() command appropriate for this type of application?

Answer (score 0):

The `readline` function simplifies the task of prompting the user for info from the command line. The [PHP:readline Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php) page is fairly straightforward, as well, since there is only one argument for the function - the prompt string.

Using `readline` would allow you to tighten things up a bit, reading values directly in the array constructor.

```php
<?php

function createNewEntry()
{
    $thearray = array(
      'Name' => readline( "Enter Practitioner Name: "),
      'email' => readline( "Enter Practitioner email: "),
      'Country' => readline( "Enter Practitioner Country: ")
    );

    return ($thearray);
}

$newprac = createNewEntry();

var_dump($newprac);
```

the output will look the same:

```
Enter Practitioner Name: Doc Watson
Enter Practitioner email: doc@picker.net
Enter Practitioner Country: Bluegrass
array(3) {
  ["Name"]=>
  string(10) "Doc Watson"
  ["email"]=>
  string(14) "doc@picker.net"
  ["Country"]=>
  string(9) "Bluegrass"
}
```